# Jobs & professional opportunities

Tags: discussion

I had a look over at Stack Exchange https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/create.
I am not sure if it would be possible to do the same with Earth Science Stack Exchange. I mean post doctoral opportunities, jobs, etc.
Perhaps not but no harm asking the question is there(by the way I am not looking for a job so no personal interest in this )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long-term plan for Stack Overflow Careers/Jobs has been to expand it across the network. From [Please don’t make Careers developers‑only in practice!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271121/please-don-t-make-careers-developers-only-in-practice):

> FWIW, I don't know what the long-term plans are for other sites, but I
>   certainly hope we wouldn't deny jobs for professionals who are active
>   on Stack Exchange just for the sake of a different URL scheme; this is
>   all about serving MORE people, not fewer! Once upon a time, the dream
>   was that every site would have an associated section for jobs, a place
>   where everyone from chefs to physicists could turn their knowledge
>   into a live portfolio... We're still a long, long way away from that,
>   but I'd like to believe that better integration with Stack Overflow is
>   the first step along that road.

As Shog9 states there though, this is a long way from happening. Careers/Jobs right now could certainly have *some* applicable jobs; some folks on here are programmers too and might be able to find a job that integrates both programming and earth science. However, for the time being, Careers/Jobs is nearly all for programming jobs. Eventually this might change, but currently that's the best we can do.